In Spades, bid + partner's bid exceeds 13
In Spades, how to score if the total bid of me and my partner is over 13?
For example, if I bid 10 and my partner bids 5, can we score even though we can only get 13 tricks?

That would only happen if you and your partner had to bid simultaneously, without either knowing the other's bid. But one partner will always know their partner's bid ahead of time, and can bid accordingly.

See more at https://spades.co/how-to-play-spades

A bid in spades is for the number of tricks the team will win, not the player. And the bid is capped at 13. If you bid 10, that's a bid for you and your partner to take 10. Your partner cannot then bid 5 for your team, since you have already bid 10 for the team.
From these rules:

Bidding Order: Starting with the player to the left of the dealer, each player bids on the number of tricks they believe their team can win during the round. Bids can range from "Nil" (winning no tricks) to "13" (winning all tricks).


Does that mean someone can bid 13, forcing their partner to go nill and possibly throw the hand to lose both bids?

@JoeW, yes. bidding 13 means your partner must bid nil.  Usually this bid will result in a -230 points for the team.

That would be an invalid bid and your partner would only be able to bid a max of 3. The total bid for a team cannot exceed 13 which is the number of possible tricks. The total bid between both teams can exceed 13 on the other hand.
If a bid of 15 was allowed the only possible outcome is for your team to go set as that bid is impossible to acheive.
